# Deleting objects in django tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following models:

```
class Poster(models.Model)
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary=True)
     userpicture = models.CharField(max_length = 128 =True)

class Posts(models.Model)
     poster = models.ForeignKey(Poster, related_name = 'post_owner')
     url = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
     time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(Poster)
     post = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
     time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     comment = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

A poster can make a post and other posters can comment on that post. Kind of like how a blog works. I would like to make it so that the post owner has the option to delete his own comments and the comments of other posters on his post.

How can I go about doing this?

I'm currently using Django Tastypie. Here is my current resource:

```
class DeleteComment(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
          queryset = Comment.objects.all()
          allowed_methods = ['delete']
          resource_name = 'comment-delete'
          excludes = ['id', 'comment', 'post', 'time']
          authorization = Authorization()
          authentication = BasicAuthentication()
          include_resource_uri = False
          always_return_data = True
```

This works however! this allows any user to delete any comment even if its not their own which is not good! How?

By simply sending a **DELETE** request to: myapp.com:8000/v1/posts/comment-delete/**8**/ it deletes the **Comment** object that has an **id** of **8**. This is where the setup is failing.

I need a way so that only the post owner of the post can delete his comments and the comments of others on his post.

Answer (score 3):

This is best enforced with [Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html).

You need to implement the `delete_detail` method to return True or False, for example:

```
def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user
```

Comment: Is obvious, but to state explicitly since apparently it wasn't to me at first, 
If `True` is returned, the object will be deleted in the obj_delete method. 
If `False` is returned, the object will not be deleted in the obj_delete. method.

 The obj_delete method is used to actually delete an object, the delete_detail decides if it is going to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [tastyie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/cookbook.html). Maybe you can do something like this:

```
class DeleteComment(ModelResource):

    def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
         # get post id
         comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=bundle.data.id) # or or whatever way you can get the id
         # delete all comments with that post id
         Comment.objects.filter(post=comment.post).delete()
         return super(DeleteComment, self).obj_delete(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: will this account for the deleting of Comment objects created by others Posters?

Comment: I tried your solution, the poster who made the comment was unable to delete his comment :(

Comment: Delete the post instead. That should delete the comment as well.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid. I know that deleting the post will delete all comments associated with it, however what I am asking is if there is a way to delete the comments without deleting the post. The Poster can delete his own comment and the comments of other posters on his own post. The reason for this is so that if the post owner makes a mistake on his comment or other posters write something offensive on his post, he can simply delete them.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, all the client is sending me is a DELETE request to this following url: myapp.com:8000/v1/posts/comment-delete/8/ .The client knows the id of the comment and puts it at the end of the url. Is there anyway I can get this id on the tastypie side? the client isn't sending me data. That's the problem. All they are doing is accessing that url as a DELETE request.

Comment: Maybe try `bundle.obj.pk`? Inspect bundle and you'll find it.

Comment: this is so weird! for some reason, obj_delete doesn't use  'bundle' as one of it's arguments. I tried to print the bundle to see what would show up but the resource wouldn't work until I erased bundle out of the arguments. I'm using tastypie 0.11

Comment: It does according to the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#obj-delete)

Comment: This will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482183/tastypie-return-data-from-delete-requests