# How to perform validation before deleting a record in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to implement a delete function. Before delete, it need to check if this record is used by another table.

I tried to overwrite:

```
  def delete_detail(self, request, bundle):

  def obj_delete(self, request=None, **kwargs):
```

But, it never get called. How to do such validation before delete?

Comment: you could override the model's delete function and do the check there? or see this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280672/deleting-objects-in-django-tastypie

Comment: Thank you. I tried to overwrite above function, but never get called. Not sure why.