# DELETEing a resource in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a `CommentResource` model in which I want to ensure that a user can delete a comment only authored by him (by sending a DELETE reqeust). So I use follow the answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280672/deleting-objects-in-django-tastypie).

```
def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user
```

But django gives me this error:

> `delete_detail()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that a user can delete a comment only authored by him (by sending a `DELETE` reqeust), you need to implement your authorization class like below.

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized

class MyAuthorization(Authorization)

    def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        """
        Returns True or false based on authorized after applying
        your logic. You can even raise an exception if unauthorized.
        """
        if authorized:
            return True
        else:
             #raise Unauthorized("Sorry, can't delete other user's comments.")
             return False
```